# .Net C# Newtonsoft issue with default attribute while DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft for JSON string to deserialize object but I could not get value for default attribute/properties

```json
{
   "displayName": "Token",
   "name": "token",
   "type": "string",
   "default": ""
}
```

C# code

```
public class ItemProperties
{
   public string displayName { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("default")]
   public dynamic defaultValue{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you need to use `[JsonProperty("default")]`. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm

Comment: `JsonPropertyName` is from  System.Text.Json  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-5.0) which is part of `System.Text.Json`. As you're using Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) you need `JsonPropertyAttribute` instead. I would actually apply it to *all* the properties, and then rename them to be have idiomatic C# names. Here's a complete example:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class ItemProperties
{
    [JsonProperty("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("default")]
    public dynamic DefaultValue { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var properties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemProperties>(json);
        Console.WriteLine($"DisplayName: {properties.DisplayName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {properties.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Type: {properties.Type}");
        Console.WriteLine($"DefaultValue: {properties.DefaultValue}");
    }
}
```

Sample JSON:

```json
{
  "displayName": "x",
  "name": "y",
  "type": "z",
  "default": 10
}
```

Output:

```
DisplayName: x
Name: y
Type: z
DefaultValue: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer it should be accessible using You can use keywords in C# as identifiers by prepending `@` in front of them

C# code

```
public class ItemProperties
{
   public string displayName { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }

   public dynamic @default { get; set; }
}
```

then you can access like `objItem.@default`.

Comment: That's an option - but as posted in the comments, using `JsonProperty` would be an alternative. That's a *better* alternative IMO, as then you can give your properties idiomatic C# names: `DisplayName`, `Name`, `Type`, `DefaultValue`.

Comment: Yes, but while deserialize it did not the data I think in header @default may work? [JsonPropertyName("@default")]

Comment: No, you're still using `[JsonPropertyName]` instead of `[JsonProperty]`. I'll add my own answer.

Comment: Yes correct your solution also worked.